# Highlight predetermined locations in textbox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been using python 3.4 and tkinter to create an application to parse logs and format data and display results in a text widget.  I would like to highlight text that is located at a known position on each line in the text window.  I have seen similar highlighting questions regarding highlighting text in text widgets on this site and it has been very helpful.

My problem is that I don't need to search for the string or characters to highlight.  I have the locations that I want to highlight and it could be any character in that location including white space.  For example: I would like to highlight positions 0, 20, 40 on each line (eg: index 1.0, 1.20, 1.40, 2.0, 2.20, etc).

Since it is large files being written to the textbox I have to do this for the entire scrollable text window, so I need to maintain the textbox line number position.

Comment: Are the "predetermined locations" simply offsets from the first character? In your example of "0, 20, 40" does that mean the first character, the 20th character, and the 40th character? Or, do those numbers represent words or lines?

Comment: No, they are the locations that need to be highlighted, so the length would be one character.  I am trying to mark the starting position of new fields on each line.  Hope this helps.

Comment: again, what is a "location"? A character? A line? If I have the value "20", is that the 20th character?

Comment: Bryan,  The character could be anything that is in that position, that is why search doesn't work for what I am attempting to do.  It could be whitespace, semicolon, special characters. It is just the starting position for each field.  The data below is an example of what is written to the textbox:  I just need to highlight whatever lands in positions 0, 20, 40, etc.
3,24403734 2 Port Gas Road,P,900GM 3734,B,24403734,C,100
1563,72146177 Electric Ave,E,ElecGen4,B,72146177,C,10

Comment: You misunderstand my question. The word "position" in your comment is unclear. If you have the position 20, is that the 20th character? The 20th line? The 20th byte? The 20th word? What does "20" represent?

Comment: Ahh, ok. Position refers to 1.0, 1.20, 1.40 for all contents sent to the textbox.  So line 2 would be 2.0, 2.20, 2.40, all the way through the entire file.  The problem I am running into is I can't keep track of all the lines in the textbox.  Search is nice for strings but i know the location to highlight..... thanks

Comment: So, are you simply asking how to iterate over every line in the text widget?

Comment: Yes, I would like to iterate through each line and then whatever single character is located at each index on each line would be highlighted.   The range is one character and can be anything, the number of lines is unknown. I am just trying to highlight whatever happens to be on each LINE at position (0, 20, 40).  So line 1 would have a yellow highlight at 1.0 to 1.1, 1.20 to 1.21, 1.40 to 1.41.  I believe that would be one character.  Then do this for every line that follows.  I know the location to highlight I just don't know how to do it for all lines.  One line would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

When referring to a location in a text widget, you can append modifiers to indicate relative positioning. For example, given the position `"1.0"`, the next position can be identified as `"1.0+1c"` (or `"1.0+1char"`). So, to highlight a single character at a given offset, make the start of the range the offset, and the end of the range one character greater.

Here's a quick hack that takes one or more "positions" and highlights that position on each line:

```
def highlight(text, tag, *positions):
    last_line = int(text.index("end-1c").split(".")[0])
    for linenumber in range(1, last_line+1):
        line = text.get("%s.0" % linenumber, "%s.0 lineend-1c" % linenumber)
        line_length = len(line)
        for pos in positions:
            if pos <= line_length:
                start = "%s.%s" % (linenumber, pos)
                end = start + "+1c"
                text.tag_add(tag, start, end)
```

usage:

```
text = Text(...)
text.tag_configure("highlight", ...)
...
highlight(text, "highlight", 0, 20, 40)
```

Comment: I understand how to highlight a range of chars.  The file is written to the textbox window.  It could be thousands of lines written to the textbox.  I want to highlight index 0, 20, 40 on all lines.  Each line will have different character in that position.  How do I highlight line 1 though 1000 location 0, 20, 40.  This is close to what I want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995193/tkinter-dynamically-changing-text-colour-of-recurring-strings-in-a-textbox  except I also need to highlight whatever is at index 20 & 40.  In this example SUCCESS is always at index 0.  Hope this helps.

Comment: To simply answer your earlier question it is a single character in those positions.  1.0, 1.20, 1.40 next line would be 2.0, 2.20, 2.40 and the next line would be 3.0, 3.20, 3.30 that get highlighted.  I am not trying to highlight from 1.0 to 1.40 or 1.0 to end of file.  I don't understand the confusion.. guess I am not clear.

Comment: @dinkjenkins: I've completely rewritten my answer.

Comment: Thanks Bryan!  Took me a little bit to figure out how to get this to work with my code.  It is exactly what I was trying to do.